# hudson cli to start job with console output

Tags: hudson

I want to start hudson job using cli command.

java -jar "hudson-cli.jar" -s http://localhost:8080/hudson/ build myjob -s

This command is starting the job successfully and waiting for it to finish.

How to get console out of the this job? 
When i start that job manually using Hudson, it prints lots of console output. I want same out to be printed in my console when i run it using cli command. Is there a way to do it?